Why is the magnetic field due to the conduction current ignored when calculating the Poynting vector for a charging capacitor?
Consider the following problem form griffiths:

which involves showing that the (magnitude) of the surface integral of the poynting vector over the boundary equals the rate of increase of electromagnetic energy stored in the capacitor. This is the solution presented by the author:

where it is indeed shown that the two are equal. The same calculation (in the same way) is done in Purcell's textbook and the Feynmann lectures. What I don't understand is why the magnetic field due to the conduction current in the capacitor as well as the wires is being ignored here. Assuming that the separation of the plates is small, upon calculation, I have shown that the magnetic field due to the conduction currents alone is actually equal in magnitude to the induced magnetic field. The same calculation is done in problem 9.3 of Purcell's: 
so I am inclined to believe my result is correct. However, since this doubles the Poynting vector and leaves the rate of change of electromagnetic energy unchanged (magnetic energy doesn't vary with time here), the flux of energy through the surface turns out to be twice the rate of increase of energy, which is clearly a contradiction of Poynting's theorem. Why can you ignore this conduction-current magnetic field, and when you take it into account, why do things seem to go wrong?

I'm not clear about what you are asking. The Purcell 9-3 solution agrees with line 2 of the solution to Griffiths 8-3. There is no "conduction current in the capacitor" at all - it isn't being neglected; it doesn't exist.

There is no contradiction here, these problems just illustrate that the same quantity can be calculated in different ways. Recall that when you first learned about displacement current, it was probably in the context of an example where the integrated form of Ampere's law gave
$$\oint_C \mathbf{B} \cdot d \mathbf{s} = \mu_0 \iint_S \mathbf{J} \cdot d \mathbf{S}$$
where the boundary of $S$ is $C$. You then probably heard that when $\mathbf{E}$ is varying in time, the right-hand side can vary depending on the choice of $S$, so for consistency we actually have to have
$$\oint_C \mathbf{B} \cdot d \mathbf{s} = \mu_0 \iint_S \left(\mathbf{J} + \epsilon_0 \frac{\partial \mathbf{E}}{\partial t} \right) \cdot d \mathbf{S}$$
which is properly independent of $S$. What that actually means is that when you compute $\mathbf{B}$ in these situations, you have a choice over how you set up the calculation. Griffiths is choosing a route that only uses the second term, and Purcell is choosing another route that only uses the first term. But you're not supposed to add the terms together. Each term gives 100% of the effect!
The real mystery is actually why Purcell's calculation gives the right answer, because it applies the Biot-Savart law to conduction current alone. Isn't Purcell missing a contribution from displacement current? Actually, if you integrate over all displacement current $\mathbf{J}_d$ in this problem, its effect on the magnetic field completely cancels out. To see this, note that
$$\nabla \times \mathbf{J}_d = \epsilon_0 \nabla \times \frac{\partial \mathbf{E}}{\partial t} = \epsilon_0 \frac{\partial}{\partial t} (\nabla \times \mathbf{E}) = - \epsilon_0 \frac{\partial^2 \mathbf{B}}{\partial t^2} = 0$$
in this particular problem, because we are assuming a constant charging rate. Since $\mathbf{J}_d$ is constant with no curl, it is a pure divergence, so it can always be written as a superposition of radial, spherically symmetric currents. Such currents produce no magnetic fields. Another way of saying this is that you can check that the full Ampere's law, with displacement current, is satisfied by the Biot-Savart expression with conduction current alone. That's why Purcell's derivation works.
This is a well-known point in electromagnetism, emphasized in Purcell and some older textbooks, and discussed in these papers: [1], [2], [3]. Griffiths is perfectly aware of it (he actually wrote one of these papers!), but I think he avoids it in his textbook to avoid student confusion. After all, if we really can just use the ordinary Biot-Savart law in this problem, what's the point in thinking about displacement current? The answer is that in other, more complicated setups where the fields change rapidly with time (so that $\partial^2 \mathbf{B} / \partial t^2$ is significant), you do need it. You've caught the fact that when Griffiths introduces displacement current, he leans on a simple example that doesn't actually need it.

If I understand you correctly, the field I obtain by applying $\oint \vec{B}\cdot \vec{dl}=\mu_{0}\vec{J_d}$ in the interior is actually the total magnetic field, not "the contribution to the magnetic field due to the displacement current term", and therefore, it is incorrect to add to it the field due to the conduction current (which turns out to be the same as the total field as the contribution due to the displacement current is 0 in the quasistatic appoximation) ?

If this is indeed the case, how would I actually go about showing the contribution from the displacement current term in all space is actually 0? Surely, this must mean that the displacement current isn't simply confined b/w the plates of the capacitor, because the Biot-Savart law for this (displacement) current doesn't give a 0 field

There is no conduction current between the plates because they are separated by a non-conducting gap!
The total displacement current between the plates (integrated over their area) equals the conduction current in the wire. That means that the sum of the conduction and displacement currents is equal to the current in the wire. This implies that for the case of an ideal capacitor, for radii larger than the radius of the capacitor plates, the Ampere-Maxwell law tells us that the magnetic field is exactly the same as for that from an infinitely long wire.
The B-field diminishes between the capacitor plates, with respect to that from an infinitely long wire, because a smaller amount of (displacement) current is enclosed by an Amperian loop and all that matters is the net (displacement plus conduction) current through that Amperian loop, not how the current behaves elsewhere.
If you are asking why don't we consider, separately, a contribution to the magnetic field between the plates from the conduction current in the wires connected to the plates? Well, you could, but an Amperian loop around the gap between the wires does not enclose any conduction current in the wires and therefore it appears they cannot contribute to the $\hat{\phi}$ component of the magnetic field in the gap. In fact, the current implies there must be a changing charge distribution at the ends of the wires, a changing electric field and therefore a displacement current density between the wires and that the simple static Ampere's law cannot be applied. If you shrank the capacitor plates such that they were no bigger than the wire, then the magnetic field would just be equivalent to the magnetic field from an infinitely long wire at all points along the wire and in the gap.
